# How To Output The Input of Console.ReadLine() Without Using A Variable

Tags: c#

I have a quick question that I could not find the answer to on google (probably because of the extreme uselessness of the real life application). My C# instructor Has a "challenge" i.e. homework where we cannot use variables of any kind. There is only one input, the year. Does anyone know how to output the year as an int or have some sort of article that could help with this?
Example Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the year: ");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine));
```

TIA, Any answer is appreciated!
(For anyone who is curious the homework is to make an Easter Sunday Calculator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

`Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));`

or

`Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));`

`Console.ReadLine()` is a function and so it should be used with parentheses `()`.

Comment: omg I am so stupid, you are right, sorry for wasting your time.